# How do I catch c0000005 exception from native dll in c#

Tags: c#, c++, native-code

I'm working with a native dll that somewhere throws a c0000005 exception (access violation) and ends up crashing my web service until the service is recycled.  Is there a way to catch the exception?

Comment: Catching access violation makes very little sense and actually .NET 4 prevents you from doing so per default. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

Comment: Disagree with comment & answers so far. Catching the exception _for the purpose of restarting the webservice_ is OK-ish. From a business viewpoint, automatic restarts beat manual restarts. Both cause downtime, but not in equal amounts.

Comment: Catching the exception **for the purpose of knowing which dll call is at fault** is also a good reason.  re-**throw** it as it is not good to ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the others... Fix the problem, but sometimes you inherit code and you just want to catch an unexpected violation in production.

In .net 4+ you can add the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute and it will come out as an Exception that you can catch.  The call stack isn't horribly useful, but it's better than nothing.

C#

```
[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public void SomeCSharpMethod()
try
{
  // call managed code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Exception");
}
```

C++

```
vector<int> myValues;
int a = myValues[1];
```

Comment: I agree with both sides: (1) fix the real problem; (2) catch the exception to better know what the real problem is.  I recommend you re **throw** the exception to avoid forgetting about it.  The purpose of catching it is to understand it, not to ignore it.

Comment: @Jerry you just made my day, i needed to get system icon under a wpf window opened by a console application; in old OS that can only crash (without even givin the 0 value as hresult), in new OS works fine. Now that i can catch the exception all work fine, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

you can catch the exception using Microsoft [SEH exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but really you should fix whatever is wrong.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Wish I could fix it, but it's in 3rd party dll.

Comment: @Marty: just because the error is *detected* in the 3rd party DLL, doesn't mean that's where the error *occurs*.  Check all inputs and read the documentation carefully.  You might be passing it bad inputs!

Comment: I disagree with all who say "it makes no sense" to catch this kind of C++ exception in a C# application.  If one could catch the exception, print out some debug information, and re-throw the exception, then one could better know _which_ call into the DLL has the bad arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Don't catch this.  Fix the bug.

`0xc0000005` is the NT error code for `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.  This means your program made a bad pointer dereference.  Put very simply this means your program crashed violently and attempting to recover is misguided.

I know you say it's a 3rd party DLL, but at very least you should debug and understand the issue.  It may be something simple like you are passing the DLL some bad input or not initializing it properly.  If you can't do that you can contact the authors of the DLL or consider eliminating your dependency on them.

Comment: You might consider that the first step to resolving the issue is to catch it first, so that you can examine the fault in more detail