# How to find error in 'The program .. has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have an uwp project testing on Win 10 iot core with raspberry pi 3. I do remote debugging on device. After a while the application crashes and only i can see in debug is that error.'The program .. has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).' how can i see more meaningful things about this. The debug is stopping after that.

**Edit**
The output in vs 2015 no more message showing.Only that error. My project is about ble devices. I am making some read and write operations with using `ConcurrentDictionary` from different threads. But all of those operations in try catch block. I cannot be sure the problem is about that because noone coming in catch.Also i have following App.cs code

```
this.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Exception);
            };
```

But this code is not hitted too.

Comment: Can you share the source code with us?

Comment: Doesn't the debug output tell you anything else? That some thread ended or some exception occurred?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470998/3387453

Comment: The exit code seems to suggest a breakpoint: http://www.support.tabs3.com/main/R10309.htm

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar error while wrapping a C++ DLL for a windows Forms application.

The issue was that I returned an unmanaged `const char*` from the C++ process and declared it as a `string` in the C# environment (that is supposed to work) but the system didn't recognize it, but didn't catch any error.

It seems to be a built-in C# behavior. I had to go through an `IntPtr` and Marshal it into a string and the error magically disappeared.

It might have nothing to do with your setting but the symptoms were the same: "Crashing of the application without warning and no exception thrown or caught."

If I were you, and if you're still struggling with this issue, I would look for issues in the DLL wrappings.

Answer (score -2):

According to [this](http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0x80000003) Wiki it is a problem with misconfigured system files. The solution is:

1) Start your computer and log on as an administrator.

2) Click the Start button then select All Programs, Accessories, System Tools, and then click System Restore.

3) In the new window, select "Restore my computer to an earlier time" option and then click Next.

4) Select the most recent system restore point from the "On this list, click a restore point" list, and then click Next.

5) Click Next on the confirmation window.

6) Restarts the computer when the restoration is finished.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the os is Windows 10 iot core.

Comment: Ok, then this will not apply directly to you. But you could still reset your system.

Comment: The message I wanted to deliver is, that it has (most likely) nothing to do with the application you are running, but with the OS settings.

Comment: @mayk did you try it?

Comment: Not now. installing the os again.

Comment: It is pretty obvious the issue comes from the code and not from the PC or the device and absolutely doesn't warrant a full system restore... It's like saying "I keep running into walls, let's destroy the house and build a new one with the same walls! maybe I won't run into them this time!"

Comment: I just provided a Link to a Wiki where this was suggested. But thanks for your colorful explanation

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I apologize if my comment was seen as rude (well it actually is rude) but what I meant was that the wiki is targeted at normal windows users encountering crashes in the normal course of their work, not as a debugging option for programmers. The issue here happens in the development process of an IOT project, and is far more likely to be caused by bad memory handling than by windows OS corruption, or that would be WAY too coincidental